# How about if $ |z-2i|<0.5$

Tags: complex-analysis

How about if it is |z-2i|<0.5

Determine the absolute  maximum value of $f(z)=\left | \frac{5z^4+4 }{z^2+1}\right |$ on the closed disk $ |z-2i|<0.5$

I broke the fraction and tried to use triangular fraction. 
$|\frac{5z^2+6}{z^2+1}|\leq 5+|\frac{1}{z^2+1}|$

Comment: Is there $z^4$ or $z^2$ in numerator .

Comment: If it is $z^2$ then for maximum of ${1 \over 1+z^2}$ , |z| should be minimum , which is the distance of any point lying in circle of radius 0.5 with centre at ( 0 , 2 ) from origin . So $min(|z|)=2 - 0.5 = 1.5$

Answer (score 1):

By the maximum modulus principle, $|f|$ can't have a local maximum on the interior of the disk $|z-2i|\lt0.5$.

Comment: @keon I'm not aware of the math behind Chris Custer's *answer*, but it seems intuitive.  Are you sure that the problem isn't $\;|z - 2i| \leq 0.5?\;$  Based on this suggested correction, I would revert to Cartesian coordinates, express y as a function of x [re a circle of radius 0.5, centered at (0,2)], express the function to be maxed as a function of x, then take the 1st and 2nd derivatives with respect to x.

Comment: i am sorry it is.

Comment: i am sorry it is<=